# How do you rescale images in HTML/CSS to have the same height?

Tags: html, css

I have (sets of) two differently-sized and shaped images within a variable-width div. I would like to rescale the images to have the same height, whilst maintaining their same aspect-ratio.

I hoped this code (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nakx7pee/)) would cause both images to have the same height as the parent div.

```
<div style="width:75%">
  <img style="height:100%" src="blue_rectangle" />
  <img style="height:100%" src="red_square" />
</div>
```

I'm happy to use tables, if this is the easiest solution.

**Edit**: to clarify, the result should look like misterManSam's solution below, with the images increasing in size (but not shape) as the page width increases.

Comment: There is no easy way—CSS alone is incapable of producing the layout to achieve. What you need is a [JS-based solution](https://medium.com/coding-design/responsive-photosets-7742e6f93d9e) (*disclosure: I am the author of the linked article*) which will retrieve the aspect ratio of the two images, and calculate the optimum height so that both images will have a combined total width that fills your division element.

Comment: Do you want the images to have the same height and width with the same aspect ratio (by cropping the image) or just the height with different widths inline?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the rest of your content, you could control the *height* of the images with the *width* of the viewport, using [viewport-width (`vw`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) lengths. The max and min height ensure that the images do not get too big.

**Compatibility:** [Mostly good — IE9+ and the most common browsers support `vw`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

#### Example

**Note:** The images provided in your example each have a different transparent border width. The black background shows the actual image width and height.

```css
img {
  height: 20vw;
  background: #000;
  max-height: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/Rectangle_example.svg/200px-Rectangle_example.svg.png" />
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/af/Basic_square.svg/200px-Basic_square.svg.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I might misunderstand your question, but isn't this just a way to make them the same height?
http://jsfiddle.net/nakx7pee/2/

```
div{
    width:75%;
    height:8em;
}
img{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    background:yellow; /* to show: same height */
}
```

(you didn't give any information about the height of the div)